# Python: Matching Strings from an Array with Substrings from Texts in another Array

Tags: python, arrays, vectorization, string-matching, data-extraction

Currently I am crawling a Webpage for newspaper articles using Pythons BeautifulSoup Library. These articles are stored in the object "details".

Then I have a couple of names of various streets that are stored in the object "lines". Now I want to search the articles for the street names that are contained in "lines".

If one of the street names is part of one of the articles, I want to safe the name of the street in an array.

If there is no match for an article (the selected article does not contain any of the street names), then there should be an empty element in the array.

So for example, let's assume the object "lines" would consist of ("Abbey Road", "St-John's Bridge", "West Lane", "Sunpoint", "East End").

The object "details" consists of 4 articles, of which 2 contain "Abbey Road" and "West Lane" (e.g. as in "Car accident on Abbey Road, three people hurt"). The other 2 articles don't contain any of names from "lines".

Then after matching the result should be an array like this:
[]["Abbey Road"][]["West Lane"]

I was also told to use Vectorization for this, as my original data sample is quite big. However I'm not familiar with using vectorization for String operations. Has anyone worked with this already?

My Code currently looks like this, however this only returns "-1" as elements of my resulting array:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import io
import re
import string
import numpy as np


my_list = []
for y in range (0, 2):
    y *= 27
    i = str(y)
    my_list.append('http://www.presseportal.de/blaulicht/suche.htx?q=' + 'einbruch' + '&start=' + i)



for link in my_list:
  #  print (link)
    r = requests.get(link)
    r.encoding = 'utf-8'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')



with open('a4.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        lines = [w.replace('\n', '') for w in lines]    


        details = soup.find_all(class_='news-bodycopy')
        for class_element in details:
            details = class_element.get_text()

        sdetails = ''.join(details)
        slines = ''.join(lines)
        i = str.find(sdetails, slines[1 : 38506])
        print(i)
```

If someone wants to reproduce my experiment, the Website-Url is in the code above and the crawling and storing of articles in the object "details" works properly, so the code can just be copied.

The .txt-file for my original Data for the object "lines" can be accessed in this Dropbox-Folder:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/o0cjk1o2ej8nogq/a4.txt?dl=0

Thanks a lot for any hints how I can make this work, preferably via Vectorization.

Comment: I am quite unsure about the second for loop where variable `soup` will be overwritten on each iterations. Anyways let me try to run your entire code and understand the issue!

Comment: The second for loop is for crawling the different pages of the website where the news reports are stored. We create a list of links, each link for one page, with the first for loop and the counter of the pagination is 27 in the URL.
However I'm having a hard time extracting the street names from the articles by matching them with the list from "a4.txt" and storing them in an array where elements without matching street names are empty and elements with matching names contain the matching name only. 
My entire code is in the post above and there is a link for the "a4.txt". @VivekHarikrishnan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
my_list = []
for y in range (0, 2):
    i = str(y)
    my_list.append('http://www.presseportal.de/blaulicht/suche.htx?q=einbruch&start=' + i)

for link in my_list:
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.decode('utf-8','ignore'), 'html.parser')

details = soup.find_all(class_='news-bodycopy')
f = open('a4.txt')
lines = [line.rstrip('\r\n') for line in f] 

result = []
for i in range(len(details)):
    found_in_line = 0
    for j in range(len(lines)):
        try:
            if details[i].get_text().index(lines[j].decode('utf-8','ignore')) is not None:
                result.append(lines[j])
                found_in_line = found_in_line + 1
        except:
            if (j == len(lines)-1) and (found_in_line == 0):
                result.append(" ")
print result
```

Comment: For some reason it is not working with the articles crawled from the website and the .txt-file that contains the street names.
But in general this solves the example. Maybe I can make it work for my specific setting with some fiddeling. In any case, thanks a lot for your suggestion. @Gunnar Sigfusson

Comment: Ok thanks,  I will take a closer look at this during the weekend, the code above should also work with the soup stuff but I see some encoding related problems (habe Erfahrung mit deutschen Buchstaben :)) which could add an extra exception. I will also try to find something better than try catch to tackle expected empty results regarding to perfomance.

Comment: @DataFreshman Sorry for late review, I did update the original answer with code that works somehow with your (modified) data. As I suggested the main problem was the incorrect encoding/decoding of your data, first the webpage-data and then there is a lot of crap in the a4.txt - file. You need to update the a4.txt file to be either rightly UTF8 encoded or just write the correct german letters where they are distorted (this will work with your german local settings). I did the latter one, I also removed a lot of single characters like C,D,E,F,G,x etc.

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the effort! Great work. @Gunnar Sigfusson